# Manipulate with value list in Django

Tags: python, django

I have a value list in Django

```
maca = Orders.objects.all().values_list("order_date")
```

But I want to manipulate with order date. It shows up as YYYY-MM-DD and I want to change the format.

For example

```
maca = Orders.objects.all().values_list(datetime.strftime("order_date", "%d/%m/%Y")
```

It is not only this case.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `order_date` is a `DateField`, you're getting a Python `datetime.date`, whose default string format is ISO8601 YYYY-MM-DD.

If you want a different format in templates, use the [`date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#date):

```
{% for date in maca %}
  {{ date|date }}
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to just use e.g. `strftime`, that's just basic Python. Be sure to add `flat=True` to `values_list` to get a list of dates, not a list of 1-tuples containing dates.

```
maca = [
    date.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")
    for date
    in Orders.objects.all().values_list("order_date", flat=True)
]
```

Comment: thanks, it worked